# Static cell reference google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a two sheets "One" and "Two"

I want column A  in "One" to reference column B in  "Two" the following works fine up to a point.

A1 = Two!B1

Then I use the fill to populate the rest of the column. The problem is in Two I continually want to add a column to the left of B which becomes the new B. I want A1 to reference the new B1, but spreadsheets automagically updates all reference in One to C instead of B. Is there a way to force B to remain static?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes.

Use $A$1 to make the reference remain static.

Read more here: http://www.gcflearnfree.org/googlespreadsheets/14.3

Comment: This isn't the accepted answer but worked for me (so I upvoted).

Comment: This doesn't work for the given question. If adding a column in the Sheet 'Two', the reference will be updated.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR;
`A1` is a reference relative to the current cell.  Copy-paste will update this reference.
`$A$1` is a static reference to a specific cell. Copy-paste will not change this reference.
[Relative and Absolute References in Google Sheets and Excel](https://it-helpdesk.tetonscience.org/support/solutions/articles/5000717879-relative-and-absolute-references-in-google-sheets-and-excel).

Spreadsheets do the heavy lifting for you, by defaulting cell references in formulas as a "relative" to the current cell.
To override this default behavior, Use a `$` sign to keep the reference "static" when pasting the formula into other cells.

For example, if you are in cell `A1` and the formula in that cell references `B1`,
then if you copy-paste this formula into cell `A2`, the formula actually pasted in the cell references `B2`.  This is generally what we want.

However, if you are in cell `A1` and the formula in that cell now says `$B$1` (it will still reference the cell `B1`, as before), but
then if you copy-paste *this* formula into cell `A2`, the formula actually pasted in the cell will still say `($B$1)` (and still reference the cell `B1`).

You can also use "mixed" references, where only the column or row is static, and the other is a dynamic reference.  For example `$B1` or `B$1`.
This link gives a good example and use case (creating multiplication tables) for mixed references, as well as static vs relative references, and warns to always use static references with `vlookup` and arrays: [Relative and Absolute References in Google Sheets and Excel](https://it-helpdesk.tetonscience.org/support/solutions/articles/5000717879-relative-and-absolute-references-in-google-sheets-and-excel).

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A1),COLUMN(A1),4,1,"One"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Indirect will returns a cell reference specified by a string. This way when a new column is added to the left of B in Sheet 'Two', you will reference the new B and not the old one (new C)

```
A1 = INDIRECT("Two!B1")
```